# Async Tasks with Controlled parallelism and AwaitAll option

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a scenario where different code from my application can call the following method

```
async Task downloadFile(string fileName)
{
    await downloadService(fileName);
}
```

Need a machanism where I can control the max number of requests it can send. For example after 5 active requests I want the rest to be queued up and next will only initiate once we get a response from one of the existing requests. I also need a machanism where I can listen to all the active/queued requests in my code something like Task.WhenAll

I am mostly interested in a built-in .Net library. I know [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) but seems like I've to implement majority of the Enqueue/Dequeue stuff myself. Wondering if a more suitable library exists.

Comment: Perhaps [System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If the number of queued up tasks is not expected to be very large, use `SemaphoreSlim` if others have suggested. If the queue is expected to get long, or if you continuously produce new tasks, and need to be able to throttle the producer, you'll need to think about employing TPL Dataflow or rolling your own mechanism which supports limiting the maximum degree of parallelism (which isn't particularly easy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) class as follows:

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);

async Task downloadFile(string fileName)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        await downloadService(fileName);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't SemaphoreSlim recommended for tasks that will finish in a very short period of time?